# computation on list using robot framework

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, robotframework

I have table in which having 10 elements.

```
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[1]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[2]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[3]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[4]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[5]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[6]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[7]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[8]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[9]
(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[10]
```

Even Aray of xpath contains names, Odd Aray of xpaths contains values.

I am trying to apply loop to get All even arays of xpath values to be stored in 1 list and all odd arays of xpaths values to be stored in another list.

Can any one please help me.

here I tried below.

```
${Count}=    get element count    10
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${Count}
        Exit For Loop If    ${i} == ${Count}
        Run Keyword if    "${Count}%2" == "0"
        ...    xpath=(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[${count}]
        ${region}=    get text    (//td[@class='psr-text small'])[${Count}]
        ...    ELSE
        ${Bin}=    get text    xpath=(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[${count}]
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
${Count}=    get element count    10
@{region}   create list   ${EMPTY}
@{Bin}   create list   ${EMPTY}
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${Count}
    IF    "${Count}%2" == "0"
       ${tmp}   get text    (//td[@class='psr-text small'])[${Count}
       Append to List   ${region}   ${tmp} 
    ELSE
       ${tmp}=    get text    xpath=(//td[@class='psr-text small'])[${count}]
       Append to List   ${Bin}   ${tmp}
END
```

in the end you will have 2 lists ('append' and 'Bin') that will contain odd and even elements respectively